# How can I get emacs to print PDF on Windows with pdftools?

Tags: windows, pdf, printing, emacs, ghostscript

If you've walked the emacs road you know how amazingly powerful it can be, and how absolutely useless.

Full disclosure: my 4800 line initialization file (soon to be 3000) does manage to load 125 useful packages in 27.5 seconds, thanks to org-babel and use-package -- but I still haven't managed to coax it into printing a pdf. Oh emacs, the simplest things right?

So of course emacs experts are a shrinking population, for obvious reasons, nonetheless I'm guessing there are at least a few here who have conquered emacs, completely. Alas, I'm not yet one of you. (yet!)

My configuration, 26.2 (build 1, x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2019-04-17, compiled with ImageMagic 7 support, pdftools, aspell 6 (which I'm not using) and a host of other windows ready gems, still pushes straight postscript into my non-postscript compatible laser printer, which promptly spits out 28 pages of garbage. BLLLLpt.

Admittedly, I know little about printing under-the-hood, but I know enough to know emacs still has one foot in last place - printing pdfs just isn't that hard. So here's the setup:

Ghostscript and ghostview for windows are installed, and added to path. Pdftools is working great, overriding docview when a pdf is opened. The init code is short.

```
(require 'printing)
```

For good measure:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "C:/Program Files(x86)/Ghostgum/gsview/gsview32.exe")
(add-to-list 'load-path "C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.26/bin/gswin64c.exe")
```

Commands (I'd prefer to set them through pr-path-alist but, well, that's not making a lot of sense).

```
(setq pr-gs-command "C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.26/bin/gswin64c.exe")
(setq pr-ps-command "C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.26/bin/gswin64c.exe")

(setq lpr-command "C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.26/bin/gswin64c.exe")
(setq ps-lpr-command "C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.26/bin/gswin64c.exe")

(setq ps-lpr-switches '("-q" "-dNOPAUSE" "-dBATCH" "-sDEVICE=mswinpr2" "-sPAPERSIZE=a4"))

(setq pr-temp-dir "c:/emacs/.emacs.d/temp/")
```

A couple of things I've tried, the ps-print.el approach and the printing.el approach. I'd prefer to use printing.els pr-interface, as it's straightforward enough.

```
lpr-buffer and lpr-region
```

Send the print job into spooling, never to be found again. My printer is a brother laser printer, the only one on the network, shouldn't lpr be better than postscript? Well nothing happens here.

print-buffer print-region to spooling with options, but nothing sent to the printer (despooling doesn't do anything either).

```
ps-print-buffer
```

Prints a text document! It spits out however 28 pages of junk with a pdf.

```
pr-ps-print-buffer
```

spooling, nothign happens

```
pr-ps-buffer-preview
```

Opens gsview (with an annoying registration popup) and previews the print job

```
pr-ps-region-using-ghostscript
```

28 pages of garbage.

So it seems likely I'm missing some basic piece of knowledge. Ghostscript is supposed to fill-in between postscript and non-postscript or pcl drivers, yes?

Am I missing a library? Or do I only need to configure initialization better?

Does anyone out there know what I'm talking about?

Comment: Odd cross posting from the [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57782105) original.

Comment: They put the original on hold and told me to post it here. Still, my view is that there is nothing 'general computing hardware and software' about emacs.

Comment: Fair enough, but pointing it out to others since your copy and paste—which I cleaned up—made it seem a wee bit spammish. I would encourage [the answer writer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57783585) to post that info here.